# How to use handlebars with nodemailer to send email?

Tags: handlebars.js, nodemailer, express-handlebars

I am using nodemailer to send emails using the following [nodemailer-express-handlebars](https://github.com/mart-jansink/nodemailer-express-handlebars) plugin. I used this {dead blog post} as reference

The code is compiling the `welcome` template but is not using the `layout`

My code is as below:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var mg = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport');
var hbs = require('nodemailer-express-handlebars');

var config = {auth: {api_key: "key-xxx",domain: "mydomain.com}}
var nodemailerTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(mg(config));

var options = {
    viewEngine: {
        extname: '.handlebars',
        layoutsDir: 'views/email/',
        defaultLayout : 'layout',
    },
    viewPath: 'views/email/'
}

nodemailerTransport.use('compile', hbs(options));

nodemailerTransport.sendMail({
        from: 'from@mydomain.com',
        to: 'to@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Welcome to the XXX',
        template: 'welcome'
    }, function (err, results) {
        if (err) console.log('Error: ' + err);
        else console.log('Response: ' + results);
});
```

My `layout.handlebars` has the following code

```
<html>
<body>
{{> _header }}
    {{{body}}}
{{> _footer }}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `partialsDir` option.

I have tested with the following options and it works fine :

```
 var options = {
   extName:'.hbs', /* or '.handlebars' */
   viewPath:__dirname+'/views/email/',
   layoutsDir:__dirname+'/view/email',
   defaultLayout:'template',
   partialsDir:__dirname+'/views/email/partials/'
 }
```

To use my directory structure :

1. Where the script is place a folder : `views`
2. Inside of it place a folder called `email` (here store 'template.hbs')
3. Inside of the email folder create a `partials` folder (here as example store 'header.hbs')

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as handlebars from 'handlebars';

import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

import * as fs from 'fs';

    async sendEmail(to: string, subject: string, text: string) {

    const templateFile = fs.readFileSync('enter the path of your template(emailTempalate.hbs) ', 'utf-8');

    // Compile the Handlebars template
    const template = handlebars.compile(templateFile);

    // Render the template with the provided context/data
    const html = template({ username: 'John Doe' });
    const mailOptions = {
      from: 'abcd@gmail.com',
      to,
      subject,
      text,
      html,
    };

    try {
      await this.transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
      return { msg: 'Email sent successfully' };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending email:', error);
      throw new Error('Failed to send email');
    }
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks almost correct, but there is a little problem with the way you specify the default layout in the options object. why not instead of defaultLayout: 'layout', use defaultLayout: 'layout.handlebars'. The full object should look like:

```
var options = {
viewEngine: {
    extname: '.handlebars',
    layoutsDir: 'views/email/',
    defaultLayout: 'layout.handlebars', // Specify the layout file including the extension
  },
viewPath: 'views/email/'
};
```

Also, make sure the layout.handlebars file is inside the layoutsDir directory and that it is correctly formatted.

Additionally, ensure that the welcome.handlebars template is correctly referencing the layout. It should have something like this:

```
{{!< layout}}
<!-- Your welcome email content goes here -->
```