# Handlebar template not showing on nodemailer email

Tags: handlebars.js, nodemailer, hbs

I'm trying to send an email using `nodemailer` with a template using `handlebars`, however, I can't get the template to show on the email. In network, the api that sends the email is showing the correct preview and response (in html) for what should be included in the template, but this information is not being displayed in the sent email. This is my first time doing this, and I have been trying to follow all the steps in examples/ tutorials on how to do this, but nothing seems to be working. I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to get my emails to send with the template. Thank you!

Note: `orders.hbs` is my `handlebars` document and is within the `views` folder

mailer.js

```
import express from 'express';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import hbs from 'nodemailer-express-handlebars';
import handlebars from 'handlebars';
import Order from './models/orderModel.js';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';



const mailerRouter = express.Router();
/*
  
  mailerRouter.engine('handlebar', exphbs());
  mailerRouter.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
  */
mailerRouter.post (
    '/order', 
expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email
    const orderId = req.body.orderId 
    const em = req.body.em;
    const sender = req.body.sender; 
    const orderNum = req.body.orderNum 
    const emailBody = await Order.findById(orderId).lean()
    if (emailBody) {
       res.render('orders', {data: emailBody})
      }
    
    const sub = `Order: ${orderId}`
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: sender,
        pass: '',
        clientId: '',
        clientSecret: '',
        refreshToken: '',
      }
    })

    /*
    transporter.use('compile', hbs({
      viewEngine: 'express-handlebars',
      viewPath:'./views/'
    }))*/
   
    const handlebarOptions = {
      viewEngine: {
        extName: '.hbs',
        partialsDir: 'views',
        layoutsDir: 'views',
        defaultLayout: '',
      },
      viewPath: './views/',
      extName: '.hbs',
    };
  
  
  transporter.use('compile', hbs(handlebarOptions));
        const mailOptions = {
        from: sender,
        to: em, 
        subject: sub, 
        text: "Hello"
        html: 'hi'
        template: 'orders',
      }
 
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
        if(err)
          console.log(err)
        else
          console.log(info);
     });
  
}))

export default mailerRouter;
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';
import hbs from 'express-handlebars';
import orderRouter from './routers/orderRouter.js';
import mailerRouter from './mailer.js';

const app = express();
app.use(cors()); 
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/AM', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
});

app.use('/api/orders', orderRouter);

const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.use('/api/mailer', mailerRouter);
app.engine('hbs', hbs({
    extname: 'hbs',
    defaultLayout: false,
    layoutDir:__dirname+'/backend/views/layouts/', 
    partialsDir: __dirname + '/backend/views/layouts',
}));
app.set('views', path.join( __dirname, '/backend/views/layouts'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server is ready');
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Edit:
So, if I have:

```
...
const __dirname = path.resolve();
const emailTemplateSource = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "backend/views/orders.hbs"), "utf8")
  
        const mailOptions = {
        from: sender,
        to: em, 
        subject: sub, 
        text: '', 
        html: emailTemplateSource,
       // template: emailTemplateSource,
...
```

The email body shows:

```
{{#each data.orderItems}}

{{name}}


{{/each}}
```

Instead of the names of the items. I have also tried adding   `const temp = handlebars.compile(emailTemplateSource)` after `const emailTemplateSource` and then changing it to `html: temp`, but this sends a blank email. I have also tried adding these after `template:` , but no matter what I put there nothing seems to show up.

Additional Info:
`console.log(emailTemplateSource)`
Gives :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    {{#each data.orderItems}}
    <div>
        <h3>{{name}}</h1>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</body>
</html>
```

And
`const temp = handlebars.compile(emailTemplateSource) console.log(temp)`
Gives: `Function: ret] {   _setup: [Function (anonymous)],  _child: [Function (anonymous)]}`

Comment: Does this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302010/how-to-use-handlebars-with-nodemailer-to-send-email

Comment: No, unfortunately that did not help. I also added my ```server.js``` document above because I have ```app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: false, layoutDir:__dirname+'/backend/views/layouts/', partialsDir: __dirname + '/backend/views/layouts',}));
app.set('views', path.join( __dirname, '/backend/views/layouts'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');```in my ```server.js```, which is a little different than that example

Comment: And what do you get when you use `console.log(emailTemplateSource)`?

Comment: It probably won't be of much help but I give you two possible solutions: Make and send the HTML in a templateString (So you can conveniently add what you want) or make the HTML in a separate HTML file, get its content as a String and use [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) to add `{{name}}` and so on, e.g.

Comment: I added ```console.log(emailTemplateSource) ``` and ```console.log(temp)``` above to the bottom of my post to format it better

Comment: Does this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56225938/sending-email-with-nodemailer-and-handlebars?rq=1